# How to format specific items in Qmenu or Toolboxes? Is it possible to define a pseudo-state or sub-control?

Tags: python, qtstylesheets, pyside2

I am trying to setStyleSheet on the BUTTON for just one option in the toolbar, namely the "menuSystem" object within the menuBar:

The structure is like:

```
NAME               Class
menuBar            QMenu
    -menuFile      QMenu
    -menuSystem    QMenu    <- Want to color just the button for this
        -action1   QAction
        -action2   QAction
        -action3   QAction
    -menuView      QMenu
```

If I use:

```
ui.menuBar.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item {background-color: rgb(80, 255, 80)}"
```

It colors all the butons (obviously)

If I use:

```
ui.menuSystem.setStyleSheet("{*same styling*}")
```

It doesn't color the 'system' button, but colors all the contents, i.e. the actions 1, 2 and 3.

On the other hand, if I use a pseudostate like :selected for instance:

```
ui.menuSystem.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item:selected {*same styling*}"
```

It colors only the button where my curser is at, including the "menuSystem"

This makes me think, is there a way to define a pseudostate using a function to catch a signal and have it applied?

Edit: I tried defining a class as suggested by @Matphy:

```
class MSystem(QMenu) :
    pass
```

in msystem.h which is in the solution, and:

```
import msystem
...
self.parent.ui.menuBar.setStyleSheet("MSystem::item {background-color: rgb(255, 80, 80)}")
```

The class of the item has been changed accordingly:

[image: screenshot]

or in the .ui file:

```
<widget class="MSystem" name="MenuSystem">
    <property name="title">
        <string>&amp;System</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QMenu" name="menuSoftware">*stuff*</wdiget>
    *and more stuff*
</widget>
```

and at the bottom:

```
<customwidgets>
    <customwidget>
        <class>MSystem</class>
        <extends>QMenu</extends>
        <header>msystem.h</header>
    </customwidget>
</customwidgets>
```

but nothing happens...

Comment: @eyllanesc, thank you so much for your help with the formatting!

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own class (inherit `QMenu`):

```
class MenuSystem(QMenu):
     pass
```

Then you write:

```
ui.menuBar.setStyleSheet("MenuSystem::item {background-color: rgb(80, 255, 80)}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Matphy! I will definitely try this out for now. The one issue is that I will have to do this for all of my menus and actions. this comes to be a lot because I have other menues besides the ones mentioned here. In this case are there any other ways you could imagine? Again, thank you!

Comment: hmm... It didn't do anything which is strange, it should have at least given me an error.